# Javascript to find out how many natural groups are formed based on numbers?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a large array of numbers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 20, 20, 35, 34, 60, 60, 61, 62]
```

I am looking for a function that I could group these numbers so that the output of the function is:

`1-4`, `20`, `34-35`, `60-62` if I specify that I want 4 groups passed to the function.

Comment: You specify 3 groups and your output has 4?

Comment: based on what criteria are you grouping them?

Comment: Did you have attempted something?  It's literally a for loop between first element and last element, and for each step, check if it's a group or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had time, so I tried it myself. Here below is an example. I have used a set to prevent duplicates. What I did was

```
1. sort the array
2. construct a set
3. loop through all elements
  3a. if first is assigned then
    3a1. check first + 1 !== current el then
        3a1_1. add to set, init first and reset step
    3a2. else incr step
  3b. else init current el as first
4. convert set to array
```

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,20,20,20, 35, 34, 60, 60, 61, 62];

// sort the numbers
const b = a.sort((el1, el2) => el1 - el2);


// use a set to prevent duplicates
const result = new Set();
let first, step = 1;
// loop through all els
for(let i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
    if (first) {
        if (first+step !== b[i]) {
           result.add( (step === 1 ? first : first + '-' + b[i-1]) );
           first = b[i];
           step = 1;
        }
        else ++step;
        
    }
    else first = b[i];
}

console.log('before', a);
console.log('after', [...result]); // TADA !
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you can sort the given array and check *if the actual value is the same as the predecessor*, then exit the loop. Otherwise, check *if the value is a real predecessor*, then assign the last array with the value, and if not, push a new array to the result set.

To get a combined result, map the joined arrays.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 20, 20, 35, 34, 60, 60, 61, 62].sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; }),
    groups = data.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        var last = r[r.length - 1] || [];
        if (last[last.length - 1] === a) {
            return r;
        }
        if (!i || last[last.length - 1] + 1 !== a) {
            r.push([a]);
        } else {
            last[1] = a;
        }
        return r;
    }, []).map(function (a) {
        return a.join('-');
    });

console.log(groups);
```